# Why are my Urdu fonts generated by FontForge broken?

Tags: fonts, font-forge, ligatures

I was editing an Urdu font with FontForge. After editing I generated fonts, but when I tested all of the characters are being displayed separately. How can I correct that?

Here is an example of that:

فونٹ ٹوٹا ہوا ہے